# How do I get the html (with js script) of a page using JSOUP

Tags: java, android, web-scraping, jsoup

I want to get the html content of a page but am unable to because of the scripts that are in the HTML file. I'm trying to use Jsoup to extract the content.
If it helps, this is the link to my issue.
[JSoup select form returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64947415/jsoup-select-form-returns-null?noredirect=1#comment114864759_64947415)

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: This answer (and a few others on that page) seem to demonstrate what you are trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61531637/2711811.  Essentially you need a separate program/library to process the web page for js - the reference uses htmlunit but another example would be selenium (and probably others).

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: If you make that an answer, I can check it.